# Javascript handling .json file's lines

Tags: javascript, org.json

How to get a json file divided by lines using java script.as it is done in python by using readlines().
I have uploaded a .json file and i need to find certain keywords in it and display those lines in which those keywords are found with their line number.
the example of json file is as given below:

```
{
    "data": [],
    "numFound": 0,
    "context": {
        "rows": "50",
        "from": "2014-01-11T17:48:40.000Z",
        "until": "2014-01-11T17:48:40.000Z",
        "start": 0,
        "query": "( json.system_version:3.4.42 json.id.discoveryServerUri:\"svcs.myharmony.com\" json.event_level:error json.crashcode:syncAbort )",
        "order": "desc"
    }

 }
```

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to read a json file "by lines". What is your use case?

Comment: We need to see your code

Comment: I want the user to upload a file and in that file i need to find certain keywords with their line numbers.

Comment: Post an example of that json

Comment: @rpax, i have posted an example. The original json file consists minimum of 2500 lines and max 8000 lines.

Comment: Now i think its clear what the question asks actually..?

Comment: @Roy The only thing left is an expected output

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to load a json file at once. You can do something like this:

```
    function loadJSON(callback) {   

              var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
              xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
              //if you want it synchronous, replace with false
              xobj.open('GET', 'json_file.json', true);
              xobj.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {
                callback(xobj.responseText);
              }
        };
        xobj.send(null);  
     }
```

And then,

```
readJSON(function(response) {
    // "read" the json
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
   //do whatever you want
 });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanx a lot.now i think i am reaching somewhere.

Comment: @user3363920 +1 would be appreciated

Comment: @rpax...can you please elaborate the answer for me. I've got really confused with the above code. Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks in advance.

Comment: @Roy I can't elaborate more my answer if you don't elaborate your question. What are you trying to accomplish? Please, edit your question

Answer (score 0):

```
var raw =  // your json file contents here
var lines = raw.replace("\r\n", "\n").split("\n")
```

Comment: @rpax Thanks for editing. Was on my mobile while posting the answer...

Comment: It happens the same thing to me sometimes. Have you tried the StackExchange App?. My mobile does not support it, maybe you can give it a try